# Which is the correct statement "tolerate against" or "tolerate with"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

I can't get this right, but I'm not sure which is the correct statement:

> We do not tolerate against pornography images.

or is it

> We do not tolerate with pornography images.

Which is the correct way of not agreeing with pornography images?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Neither. *To tolerate* is a transitive verb and doesn't require any prepositional complement. So you just say:

> We do not tolerate pornographic images.

Also note that using the adjective *pornographic* is better than the noun *pornography* in this case.

Answer (score 5):

Skip the preposition altogether.

> We do not tolerate pornographic images.

*Tolerate* takes a direct object without any assistance from prepositions.